# How to config TypeScript for a C# project

Tags: javascript, c#, json, typescript, config

I think TypeScript isn't usually associated with C#, unless it is ASP.NET application. In my case I need to use TypeScript in a normal C# ConsoleApp.
I created a .NET ConsoleApp in C# in Visual Studio 2017(Not Visual Studio Code - everything I found on google about the issue I have is related to VSCode). The thing is that I'm trying to create a simple web server using C# `HttpListener` object. I did all the request-response thing and everything is working. However, now I'm coding the actual website in HTML + JavaScript and I choose to work on this in the same project so my solution explorer looks like this:

```
/Solution "HTTP"
├────HTTP
|     ├────Properties
|     ├────References
|     ├────App.config
|     ├────Program.cs
|     ├────Other C# classes...
|     └────Site_source
|               ├────media
|               |      ├───favicon.io
|               |      └───other images/videos/audios...
|               ├────scripts
|               |      ├───script.js
|               |      └───other scripts...
|               ├────index.html
|               └────other html pages... 
| 
└────────────────
```

Now after I wrote all this hierarchy tree I realized I can just attach a ScreenShot, but I will leave the hierarchy:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYV3T.png)
The idea is that the website is built in the same project solution, which creates compatibility issues.
I installed TypeScript SDK, but the .ts files don't have syntax highlighting, so I installed the `node.js` web development package from the Visual Studio Installer, even if I don't need/want/know to use the `node.js` library. I have no idea about `node.js`, I just wanted the syntax highlighting feature for TypeScript/JavaScript. I created in the scripts folder(in the solution hierarchy tree) and it seems to work. When I save the `.TS` file with `CTRL + S`, the `.JS` file is generated. However I have a problem:
This `math.ts` file:

```
class Vector2{
   x: number;
   y: number;
   constructor(x: number, y: number){
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }
}
```

It gets compiled into `math.js`:

```
var Vector2 = (function () {
    function Vector2(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    return Vector2;
}());
```

Which I know it is because it uses by default `ES3` JS version as compilation target, so I added the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [ "DOM", "ESNext" ], //tried with ...
    "module": "ESNext", //tried with ...
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ESNext", //tried with ES5, ES6, ES2015-2017
  },
  "include": [
    "*.ts"
  ],
}
```

After adding this, the `ts` compiler continued to use `functions` instead of `classes`, plus after I watched some tutorials on YouTube, it says that for auto-compile feature to add this option in `tsconfig.json`: `"watch" : true`. For me, the auto-compile on save feature was enabled without `tsconfig.json`, so it means that the `tsconfig.json` is ignored by the compiler. I want to mention that I tried to place the `tsconfig.json` everywhere(where the `.ts` files are placed in `scripts` folder, I tried on the `solution` folder, I tried on `Site_source` folder, I tried on `HTTP` folder), it doesn't work.

I also tried to manually compile the `math.ts` file using this command(after I added `tsc.exe` folder to `Control Panel` -> `Environment Variables` ):

```
tsc math.ts -t ES6
```

This works, the output `math.js` is using `class` not `function`, however I want this to work for the auto-compile feature, so I need to make this work in one of these ways:

- Make the compiler to use the `tsconfig.json`
- Access the command line and add `-t ES6` argument to the command

I know this happens because the project isn't a `Node.js` one, but a Console App .NET in C#, but there must be a way to make this work.

I need for the compiler to compile after pressing `CTRL + S`

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have `node`/`npm`/`tsc` installed. If you can run `tsc` (you can) that's enough.
2. Make sure your TS project folder has `tsconfig.json`. No point in placing it to root directory of c# project, place it either in JS/HTML or even in JS folder.
3. Open the TS project folder with console (`cmd`/`pwsh`/`wt`/whatewer). Run `tsc --watch`. The watcher should compile exsting ts files and start watching for ts file changes (file saving).
4. Tsconfig should mention all ts file globs OR do not have `include` at all. Your `*.ts` is not `**/*.ts` you want. I recomment removing `include` then it'll just compile all the files.
5. Output format depends on what features you need. Fo you need to support 2015 browsers? Do you want your files to import each other? Do you wand the whole generated JS to be one big file? That depends.

- as you don't care about exact config, just generate a tsconfig by `tsc --init`, and change `module` to "none"(if you want plain js) or "es2022" (if you want `import`-ing other scripts, requires `<script type="module">`)

Comment: I want `math.ts` -> `math.js`, `script1.ts` -> `script1js`, `script2.ts` -> `script2.js`, ..., `scriptN.ts` -> `scriptN.js`. And I don't care about support, since this is a project I need for a license at highschool and I will present it in a modern browser, and it won't have a real use beyond that(It will never be published, I port forwarded my pc in my local network interface and I will keep the server running home while I present it, and then close it forever)

Comment: @BogdanFloares then use `tsc --init`, I've updated text

Comment: But why is TypeScript so dependent on Node.js, I mean, TypeScript can be used on client-side programming like vanilla JS, correct?

Comment: Where to use `tsc --init`? If I could use cmd I would use `tsc  math.js -t ES6`

Comment: @BogdanFloares tsc --init cheates tsconfig.json in current folder. So if html/js of js folder, see #2

Comment: @BogdanFloares because TS compiler is a nodejs app

Comment: I ran `tsc --init` and it created a config file, but the compiler ignores it

Comment: When I press CTRL + S, VS starts a tsc.exe process, correct? Why it doesn't let me modify the parameters?

Comment: I don't understand what you said here: `tsc --init cheates tsconfig.json in current folder. So if html/js of js folder, see #2`

Comment: Update: Looks like if I run the command `tsc` with no arguments in the folder containing the `.ts` files, they are compiled correct, using `tsconfig.json`, so it looks like the problem is with the VS auto-compiling on save

Comment: @BogdanFloares 1) No, the `tsc --watch` process should be always active, listening on filesystem for file changes and immediately compoling into js. 2) `tsc --init` CREATES a tsconfig.json file with descriptions